# How can I iterate inside a class attribute?

Tags: python

So, I have this code

```
import itertools


def parse_dssp(dsspfile):
        dssp={}
        fdssp=open(dsspfile)
        c=0
        for line in fdssp:
                if line.find('  #  RESIDUE')==0:
                        c=1
                        continue
                if c==1:
                        ch=line[11]
                        num=line[5:10].strip()
                        res=line[13]
                        ss=line[16]
                        if ss==' ':ss='C'
                        el=(ch,num,res,ss)
                        asa=float(line[35:38].strip())
                        phi=float(line[103:109].strip())
                        psi=float(line[109:115].strip())
                        dssp[el]=[asa,phi,psi]
        return dssp


def interaction_surface(mono1,mono2,comp):
        count_trimer=sum([mono2.ot[i][0] for i in mono2 if i[0]==mono1.name])
        count_comp=sum([comp[i][0] for i in comp if i[0]==mono1.name])
        return abs(count_trimer-count_comp)


class monomer:
        def __init__(self,name,monomer,opposite_trimer):
                self.mono=monomer
                self.name=name
                self.ot=opposite_trimer
        def __iter__(self):
                for each in self.ot.keys():
                        yield self.ot.__getattribute__(each)


A=monomer('A',parse_dssp('A.dssp'),parse_dssp('BCD.dssp'))
B=monomer('B',parse_dssp('B.dssp'),parse_dssp('ACD.dssp'))
C=monomer('C',parse_dssp('C.dssp'),parse_dssp('ABD.dssp'))
D=monomer('D',parse_dssp('D.dssp'),parse_dssp('ABC.dssp'))
ABCD=parse_dssp('ABCD.dssp')
chains=[A,B,C,D]


mono=[A,B,C,D]
for m1,m2 in itertools.combinations(mono, 2):
        print(interaction surface(m1,m2,ABCD))
```

which I need for parsing DSSP files and get the interaction surface between various monomers in a molecule. In the function `interaction_surface(mono1,mono2,comp)` I need to see if the name of the monomer being analyzed in each complex (`i[0]`) corresponds to the name of mono1, so I figured I might use a class and create the attribute "name" for it.

The problem with this is that of course a class is not iterable so I tried to make self.ot iterable but with no succes yet and Python just returns `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable`. Any idea of how I could make this happen or just make the whole code more elegant and easy flowing?

Comment: If I understood what you want to do correctly, it looks like you want to have a list of monomers (for instance called `monomers`) inside a `Complex` class, and then do your list comprehension with `complex_1.monomers`.

Comment: Which line is generating the error message?

Comment: @larsks the error is certainly at `[mono2.ot[i][0] for i in mono2 if i[0]==mono1.name]`, since mono2 is an object of the `Monomer` class, which is not iterable.

Comment: Sure, but since anna is new I was trying to point out that it's much better to include complete information about the error in the question.

Comment: Yeah I'm very sorry, this is the first time I post a question! The error is in the line mentioned by @jpnadas. Thinking about it I might as well just create each monomer as a list, ex ```A=['A',parse_dssp('A.dssp'),parse_dssp('BCD.dssp')]```, and call for positional arguments instead of attributes of a class

Comment: Can you explain what the code is meant to do? Can you share some data? Please see: [mcve].